# Unexpected error when am trying to print a simple number in prolog

Tags: prolog

Am working on an exercise which I have to make some things. There am creating a " Function " which calculates the pow(2,c) where c is a counter and if counter goes greater than a static numbers which I have put the "function" must returns the number c. The issue is that when am trying to test it the compiler runs a couple of errors and after that the program goes down and I dont know why can anyone help me ?
I am testing it like :
num(2,1,C,6,M). where 6 is the static number that I have set which am comparing with the counter C where C is the result of the "function" pow3 which is working fine.
The main problem is at "function" num.
my code

```
num(A,B,C,D,M) :- pow3(A,B,C),Y is (B+1),num(A,Y,C,D,M).
num(A,B,C,D,M) :- C > D,M is C.

pow3(X,Y,Z) :- powend(X,Y,1,Z),!.

powend(_,0,A,Z) :- Z is A.
powend(X,Y,A,Z) :- Y1 is Y - 1, A1 is A*X, powend(X,Y1,A1,Z).
```

the errors am getting are :

```
 1) trail stack overflow 
 2) cstr stack overflow
 3) global stack overflow
 4) local stack overflow
 5) Program terminated
```

Comment: there seems to be an infinite recursion in your first clause of `num/5`

Comment: @gusbro it sould calculate 2^1 checks 2<6 then 2^2=4 checks 4<6 and after prints 8 because 2^3 =8 and 8>6 I cant understand why this infinite recursion appears I think I made it as simple as I can

Comment: @gusbro do you know how i can fix it ?

Comment: you can add a guard after calling pow3 to check that the number is within limits. However i believe you have other problems. Seems like C should be uninstantiated for the first clause, but instantiated for the second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, once the first power is calculated, variable `C` turns into constant `1`.

To solve that, at each recursive call, a fresh variable `C1` must be used.

Moreover, a condition for the execution of the recursive case must be explicitly defined.

```
num(_, _, C, D, M) :- C > D, M is C.
num(A, B, C, D, M) :- C =< D, pow3(A,B,C1), Y is B+1, num(A,Y,C1,D,M).
```

Example:

```
?- num(2,0,1,6,M).
M = 8 ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !